# Is it possible to stop all events that start from an element?

Tags: jquery

Here is what I want to do: I have this handler that handles the clicking of a link:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.ajax.get', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(){alert('Success!');});
});
```

Later on I created this handler so I could ask for user confirmation before the action takes place:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[data-confirmation]', function(){
   return confirm($(this).data('confirmation'));
});
```

This handler is placed at the top of my script

The markup that causes me problems is something like this:

```
<a href="do/something/there" class="ajax get" data-confirmation="Are you sure you want to do that?">
    Click me!
</a>
```

What I thought It would do is that when the user clicks "Cancel" on the confirmation box, the callback would return `false` and the event chain would stop. This doesn't happen, and the link gets 'clicked' no matter what the user chooses in the confirmation box.

Am I doing something wrong, or this is not possible?

Comment: Try something like `if(confirm('Are you sure?')) ......`

Comment: Why do(/would) you create a separate handler for confirmation? I don't understand why you can't combine it with the first handler..

Comment: I want to be able to use it on any element, no matter what events it triggers, that's why. If that isn't possible I can always go back to adding the check on the .ajax.get handler...

Comment: Then you should look at event bubbling, and preventing it. See my comment on sushanth's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[data-confirmation]', function(e) {
    var check = confirm($(this).data('confirmation'))
    if (!check) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        $.get($(this).attr('href'), function() {
            alert('Success!');
        });
    }
});​
```

Check [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/VHk6h/)

No request was sent when cancel button is clicked

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/VHk6h/2)

Comment: It worked for me in the fiddle above.. No request was being sent in the browser when cancel was clicked

Comment: That would be fine it there was only that event I wished to be canceled. I updated your fiddle so you can see that the request gets sent no matter what you click http://jsfiddle.net/VHk6h/1/

Comment: JS fiddle blocks the links that point to other sites, but if you open the element inspector you will see that the request is fired no matter what you choose

Comment: I don't know if the code in your Fiddle is efficient, but what's causing your problems is called event bubbling. To prevent that, use `e.stopPropagation();` to cancel out all event propagation. More in the official documentation: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: preventDefault stops the default event of the anchor.. that is happening here.. But after that is done you are sending a $get request which is not cancelled in any way .. so obviously it will try to send a request right

Comment: Also you are basing not to send the request .. But in a way you are assigning two separate events to the same element.. And it would defeat the cause you are trying to achieve.. Why not club them into the same event..  http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/VHk6h/2/

Comment: What I wanted to achieve is to make the confirmation handler in such way, so it would be possible to use the same handler on any type of element and cancel any type of events that can flow from there. If that is not possible, of course I'll have to add the code in the handler itself

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably be better off condensing everything into a single function, just check if the currently clicked element has the `data-confirmation` attribute, and if so, display the confirmation (and handle it!)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('body').on('click', 'a.ajax.get', function(e) {     
    if($(this).data('confirmation') !== undefined) { 
      if(!confirm($(this).data('confirmation'))) {
        e.preventDefault(); return false;
      }
    }

    $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(){
      alert('Success!');
    }); 
  });

});
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deifwud/P9PsP/4/)